# Accessing IPv6 addresses through an SSH tunnel

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, arch-linux, ipv6, ssh-tunnel

I have a remote Arch Linux server which has IPv6 enabled (through Tunnelbroker, I am able to do `ping6 ipv6.google.com` successfully) and I want to know if it's possible to use PuTTY on my Windows 7 machine to SSH tunnel to the Linux server and get IPv6 enabled pages to load in Google Chrome.

Comment: I think the ipv6-to-ipv4 gateway at [sixxs.org](http://www.sixxs.net/tools/gateway/) is an easier way and I think putty works.

Comment: It was, but sixxs is closed by 6/6/2017 :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible.

There are many articles as regarding setting up SSH between Windows and Linux.
Some that were picked at random:

[Configure OpenSSH To Listen On an IPv6 Address](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-bsd-unix-configuring-ssh-listen-ipv6-addresses/)
[how to ssh to a ipv6 ubuntu in a LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/236993/how-to-ssh-to-a-ipv6-ubuntu-in-a-lan)

Specific PuTTY Configuration issues are detailed in [The SSH panel](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh) of the manual.

If you wish to see graphics from Linux on Windows see :
[Use PuTTY and XMing to see Linux graphics via SSH on your Windows computer](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/2009/12/use-putty-and-xming-to-see-linux.html)

Answer (score 0):

The network devices in route to Arch linux must support. Can you ping -6 "your arch linux hostname" from your windows box. If it returns then putty should not have any problem in connecting to linux host.

Answer (score 0):

You can open `Powershell` and use

```
ping -6 2001:0db8:your:ipv6::addr
```

Then you can add a Connection in Putty, there you can just enter your ipv6 address in the host field and everything works as usual