# How do I use mDNS for ssh -6?

Tags: ipv6, avahi, ad-hoc-network

Hello I have the following setup:

1. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Laptop
2. A lot of Raspberry-Pi Model 2 with WLAN

The complete setup is based on **802.11 WLAN AD-HOC** mode. None of the Pis nor the Laptop uses any *static IPs (No IPv4 and IPv6)* The only address available are the **IPv6 Link-Local Addresses** `fe80::`

Every Pi has the **avahi-daemon** on it and I am using *mdns* on each of them. Hence I could ping them using their `.local` names. viz.

```
ping6 -I wlan0 hydrogen.local
ping6 -I wlan0 radium.local
```

The only concern is why can't I use `ssh` and `scp` with the `.local` names of the Pis.

I can perform task with the Link-Local addresses viz.

```
ssh -6 pi@fe80::a1b2:c3ff:fed4:f5g6%wlan0
scp -6 someFile.txt pi@[fe80::a1b2:c3ff:fed4:f5g6%wlan0]:/home/pi/
```

but *cannot* use

```
ssh -6 pi@hydrogen.local%wlan0
scp -6 someFile.txt pi@[radium.local]%wlan0:/home/pi/
```

Although I have Pis from the same manufacture which makes typing the MAC addresses less difficult It would be easier for an end user to use the mdns names? Any solution for this?

my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` on the Ubuntu Laptop is follows:

```
hosts:      files mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns
networks:       files
protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: What error exactly do you get when you use `hydrogen.local`?

Comment: in scp it says that the arguments are incorrect and ssh it gives pretty much the same. I am not currently at the workplace to give you the exact errors but will reproduce them tomorrow.

Comment: @DerfK `ssh: Could not resolve hostname hydrogen.local%wlan0: Name or service not known`
same for `ssh -6 pi@[hydrogen.local]%wlan0` and `ssh -6 pi@[hydrogen.local%wlan0]`

Comment: According to [this post from 2010](https://blogs.gentoo.org/eva/2010/12/17/things-you-didnt-known-about-ipv6-link-local-address/) %interface only works with an ip6 *address*, not a hostname.  It looks like the situation hasn't changed since then.  See also [this Q/A](http://superuser.com/a/237000/55979)

Comment: I think You are right. I followed the Q/A for a long time but no luck with mDNS ! oh well! Thanks anyways

Comment: Thinking about it, you might be able to do this if you use `ssh -o BindAddress=fe80::localinterfaceaddress hydrogen.local` to force ssh to bind to the correct ipv6 interface, but you'll have to look up the correct ipv6 address for your local interface.

Comment: That could be a good alternative since anyways the LL-addresses are unique and the names are pre-defined to each device anyways.